# FindByEmailAsync() returns null always

Tags: asp.net-core

My test code is for creating a new user if there isn't existed.
and it check if user is existed, using FindByEmailAsync() method.
but It returns null always, so it's creating same many users.

```
 public HomeController(
    IUnitOfWork unitOfWork, 
    UserManager<User> userManager)
{
    _unitOfWork = unitOfWork;
    _userManager = userManager;
}

public async Task<IActionResult> Index()
{
    var test = await _userManager.FindByEmailAsync("admin@admin.com");

    if (test == null)
    {
        // Add the user
        var newUser = new User
        {
            UserName = "mark",
            Email = "admin@admin.com",
            Created = DateTime.Now,
            Updated = DateTime.Now
        };

        _unitOfWork.UserRepository.Insert(newUser);
        _unitOfWork.Save();

        // password is 'admin'
        await _userManager.CreateAsync(newUser, "admin");
    }

    return View();
}
```

Here is my startup.cs

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    // add Identity
    services.AddIdentity<User, IdentityRole>(config =>
    {
        config.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
        config.Password.RequiredLength = 4;
        config.Cookies.ApplicationCookie.LoginPath = "/Auth/Login";
    })
    .AddEntityFrameworkStores<MyContext>();

     /// ...
}

public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env, ILoggerFactory loggerFactory)
{
    app.UseIdentity();

    /// ...
}
```

Also `config.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;` is not working, because it's creating multiple users with same email address, but I don't see any an error.

What am I doing wrong? please advise me.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Internally the `UserManager` is actually searching on the `NormalizedEmail` column. I would look in the database and see if that is getting populated correctly or not.

Comment: NormalizedEmail, NormalizedUserName will be null if you merge from Microsoft.AspNet.Identity

Comment: I have checked in the Normalized column there is data present but still, it doesn't work when I do forget the password and call the following code:  await UserManager.FindByEmailAsync(inputEmailAddress);

Answer (score 0):

I know this question already has an answer but for me the challenge was that the project was connected to the wrong database. You should also clarify that.